# Trying to create a bin-file using stream

Tags: c#, stream, binaryformatter

I onced managed to create the bin-file in my project. I changed the primary key from int to Guid and moved code from Main to my class Quote. At the moment I can only add new entries in said file. If I remove it a new file(0 bytes) is created and the stream gets ***ArgumentException*** when I try to feed the file dummy-data. I am trying to use an if-loop to handle stream.Lenght == 0.

```
public static List<Quote> readBinaryToList()        //Crashes if binfile is 0 bytes long
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\quotes.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    if (stream.Length == 0)
    {
        Quote q = new Quote(Guid.NewGuid(), "Quote dummy", false);
        List<Quote> quoteList = new List<Quote>();
        quoteList.Add(q);
        var bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        bformatter.Serialize(stream, quoteList);

        bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        List<Quote> quoteListTmp = (List<Quote>)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);

        return quoteList;
    }
    else
    {
        List<Quote> quoteList = (List<Quote>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
        return quoteList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in previous answers, you must give your file stream write permissions which can be done in its constructor, then you should also set the position of the stream back to 0, you can achieve this by using the stream's Position property.

You are creating a lot of unnecessary objects that don't actually contribute to purpose of the method I have omitted these below. In doing so, setting the streams Position property to 0 is redundant but I've left it in a comment to show how its done.

Some other things to consider: Declare the file stream inside a using statement so that it is disposed when the method comes to an end this means you can omit the manual close in the else statement. Some of your code can be written more tersely, this is just a personal preference but I think it would be best to inline some of your code to remove as much noise as possible. It is also convention in C# to use PascalCase for Methods.

```
public static List<Quote> ReadBinaryToList(){
  using(Stream stream = new FileStream(@"quotes.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
       IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        if (stream.Length == 0) {
           List<Quote> quoteList = new List<Quote> {new Quote(Guid.NewGuid(), "Quote dummy", false)};
           formatter.Serialize(stream, quoteList);
           //stream.Position = 0;
           return quoteList;
        }
        else return (List<Quote>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);               
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me. I am cleaning up the code now AND renaming my methods in a proper manner.

This is my first attempt working with stream, bin and I had a hard time getting over the hump. All that is left is repeating and getting a proper understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The file is being opened as readonly, serializing to the file will require write permissions.

```
Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\quotes.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

The stream should also be returned to the beginning before making any attempts to deserialize from it.

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

FileStreams have a single "head" where all read and write operations take places. As a new stream is being written, the head is always at the end and any attempt to read from the end will fail. Some streams (e.g. `NetworkStream`) behave differently and do not allow seeking at all.

Also, the initial position of the FileStream depends on how the file is opened (based on the specified `FileMode`). The FileMode specified in the question will result in the stream position starting at the beginning of the file, so this is not required in the `else` block.

And make sure that the Quote class is marked `[Serializable]`

Comment: stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); + ReadWrite Was the solution. My class was [Serializable] else it would not have worked at all. :)

Could you please explain why I needed to position like this? I didn't have to when my PK was an int and I didn't need to when my bin had entries.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Added some explanation. Changing int to Guid wouldn't have any impact here so I'm guessing something else was changed in the move from Main() to the Quote class.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the additional explanation. I am on firmer ground now when I push on in my little project. Sorry for my late response, I was out of town.